# What is com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1?

Tags: install, error, pkg

After double-clicking on a .pkg file, the Installer gives following error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed.
(com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)
Couldn't open "[filename].pkg".
```

What does this mean? Is the problem caused by the .pkg file?